# Do I need a controller for this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

As we all do, I have a Users controller/model.

I want to add a 'favorite_car' model to pull their favorite cars from the favorite_cars table in the database. In models/users.rb I have `has_many favorite_cars` and in models/favorite_car.rb I have `belongs_to user`

Can I use and store data this way without a favorite_cars controller?

Comment: Agree with tadman, if this is an individual entity then you should have a controller to perform CRUD on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update 'Favorite Car' from the user create form, look at accepts_nested_attributes. (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Your user model would then "accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorite_car".  In your view you can combine the user form fields and the car form fields and post back to the user controller.

If you want to access the favorite_car model outside of its association with a user, it would definitely need its own controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is typical to have a controller associated with each type of model you are able to create, read, update or destroy as this maps quite neatly to the REST methodology.

If you have a `FavoriteCar` model, you should probably have a `FavoriteCarsController` associated with it to help create these. If the model itself is actually a join between `User` and `Car`, you may add this as a method to the `CarsController` as an action `favorite` which does the same thing.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks -- I'd like to be able to update 'Favorite Car' in the user creation form -- is that possible, since they are separate models and tables?

Comment: If there's a relationship between User and FavoriteCar then you should be able to use `nested_attributes` to do that, but that's a separate question.